# seekg, tellg, zero-based counting and file size

Tags: c++, file-io, fstream, ifstream

So, I am curious as I've been using this rather useful approach to get the size of the file, but something bothers me. Locking a stream to a file on the file system and

```
fileStream.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
int beginning = fileStream.tellg();
```

yields 0. That's to be expected, we use the benefits of zero-based counting. What is interesting to me is that a file of 512 bytes would have positions in the range of [0, 511], therefore, returning the value of

```
fileStream.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
int end = (int)fileStream.tellg(); // We don't care for +4GB here
```

should yield 511 for end, because that's the last byte. The last position within the file loaded. So any buffer used to read in the stream would only get 511 bytes, rather than 512 bytes.

But it works, so you can see my confusion. What gives? I'm at a loss. Where does the +1 come?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After,

```
fileStream.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
```

the file pointer is position **just after** the last byte (#511). This is what the number 512 indicates. Here, 511 would mean **just before** the last byte.

Let's consider a file that's two bytes long:

- position 0 is before the first byte;
- position 1 is before the second byte;
- position 2 is before the (non-existent) third byte, i.e. at the end of the file.

Comment: Awesome, figured there should be some value to signal eof and beyond, thanks! I'll mark it as the answer when SO lets me.

Comment: @FractalResurgence there is no eof value in binary files

Comment: @Deepak What is the #512 value called then if not the eof value? It's a figure of speech, to me at least.

Comment: #512 is the offset where next byte will be written, eof value is generally -1 which is not written in files